# Issue in Image scrolling vertically

Tags: android

I have to load the view in webview by executing its url,and the two relative layouts there in Linearlayout i hide one at the time showing url in webview,it have scroll on both vertical and horizontal,the problem i'm facing here is it
 only scrolls horizontally only but i need to view it also in vertical also,

here the xml code for layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginTop="5dip" android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
              android:scrollbars="none">
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                     android:id="@+id/jr_lb_view_preview">
        <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/jr_lb_content_iv_progress"
                     android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/pb" />
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/jr_lb_content_iv"
                   android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:layout_width="150dip"
                   android:layout_height="225dip" android:background="@drawable/border"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/jr_lb_wb_view" android:background="@drawable/border"
                    android:scrollX="1dip">             
         <WebView android:id="@+id/jr_lb_view_preview_switcher2"
                android:layout_width="308dip" android:layout_height="305dip"
                android:background="@drawable/border" android:scrollbars="vertical" 
                android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

the activity code

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    preview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    g.setSelection(gPosition);
    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.jr_lb_view_preview_switcher2);
    webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    new Task_Item_Selected().execute();   
    webview.loadUrl(product_img_large[gPosition]);
    webview.setVisibility(WebView.VISIBLE);
    preview2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      // applyRotation(0, 0, 90);

   }
```

anybody help me fix it,
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

change your layout height as "FILL_PARENT" or "MATCH_PRAENT"